# tower defense game in as3 adding the enemy

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

ok so i have been creating tower defense game off of a tutorial. I finished the tutorial and it worked fine but i couldn't figure out how to build off of it. So I started all over and built more towers and a second enemy but the problem is that on the first level it works but in the second level it doesn't. I've been working with this for hours i have not found anything. so what i am asking if someone can give me a tutorial or anything that might be of help on arrays and tower defense games in as3 it is kind of a lot of code so i wont post it now unless you really need it

heres the tutorial http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-tower-defense-game-in-as3-part-1/

```
stop();
//othervariables
var money:int=100;//how much money the player has to spend on turrets
var lives:int=20;//how many lives the player has
//lvlarray
var S:String = 'START';
var F:String = 'FINISH';
var U:String = 'UP';
var R:String = 'RIGHT';
var D:String = 'DOWN';
var L:String = 'LEFT';

var startDir:String;//the direction the enemies go when they enter
var finDir:String;//the direction the enemies go when they exit
var startCoord:int;//the coordinates of the beginning of the road
var lvlArray:Array = new Array();//this array will hold the formatting of the roads

lvlArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,R,1,1,D,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,
            S,D,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,R,1,F,
            0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,R,1,1,U,0,0,R,1,1,U,0,0,R,1,1,U,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
            ];
//enemy1array
var currentLvl:int = 1;
var gameOver:Boolean = false;

var currentEnemy:int = 0;//the current enemy that we're creating from the array
var enemyTime:int = 0;//how many frames have elapsed since the last enemy was created
var enemyLimit:int = 12;//how many frames are allowed before another enemy is created
var enemyArray:Array = new Array();//this array will tell the function when to create an enemy
var enemiesLeft:int;//how many enemies are left on the field
enemyArray = [//defining the array
            [2,2,1,1,1],//1's will just represent an enemy to be created
            [1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],//another row means another level
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
              ];

function startGame():void{//we'll run this function every time a new level begins
    for(var i:int=0;i<enemyArray[currentLvl-1].length;i++){
        if(enemyArray[currentLvl-1][i] == 1){
            enemiesLeft ++;
        }
    }
}
//enemy2array
var currentEnemy2:int = 0;//the current enemy that we're creating from the array
var enemy2Time:int = 0;//how many frames have elapsed since the last enemy was created
var enemy2Limit:int = 15;//how many frames are allowed before another enemy is created


function start2Game():void{//we'll run this function every time a new level begins
    for(var i:int=0;i<enemyArray[currentLvl-1].length;i++){
        if(enemyArray[currentLvl-1][i] == 1){
            enemiesLeft ++;
        }
    }
}
//lvlcreate
var roadHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();//create an object that will hold all parts of the road
addChild(roadHolder);//add it to the stage
function makeRoad():void{
    var row:int = 0;//the current row we're working on
    var block;//this will act as the block that we're placing down
    for(var i:int=0;i<lvlArray.length;i++){//creating a loop that'll go through the level array
        if(lvlArray[i] == 0){//if the current index is set to 0
            block = new EmptyBlock();//create a gray empty block
            block.graphics.beginFill(0x333333);
            block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            block.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(block);
            //and set the coordinates to be relative to the place in the array
            block.x= (i-row*22)*25;
            block.y = row*25;
        } else if(lvlArray[i] == 1){//if there is supposed to be a row
            //just add a box that will be a darker color and won't have any actions
            block = new Shape();
            block.graphics.beginFill(0x111111);
            block.graphics.drawRect(0,0,25,25);
            block.graphics.endFill();       
            block.x= (i-row*22)*25;
            block.y = row*25;   
            roadHolder.addChild(block);//add it to the roadHolder
        } else if(lvlArray[i] is String){//if it's a string, meaning a special block
            //then create a special block
            block = new DirectBlock(lvlArray[i],(i-row*22)*25,row*25);
            addChild(block);
        }
        for(var c:int = 1;c<=16;c++){
            if(i == c*22-1){
                //if 22 columns have gone by, then we move onto the next row
                row++;
            }
        }
    }
}
//towers
function makeTurret(xValue:int,yValue:int):void{//this will need to be told the x and y values
    var turret:Turret = new Turret();//creating a variable to hold the Turret
    //changing the coordinates
    turret.x = xValue+12.5;
    turret.y = yValue+12.5;
    addChild(turret);//add it to the stage
}

function makeTurret2(xValue:int,yValue:int):void{//this will need to be told the x and y values
    var turret2:Turret2 = new Turret2();//creating a variable to hold the Turrettwo
    //changing the coordinates
    turret2.x = xValue+12.5;
    turret2.y = yValue+12.5;
    addChild(turret2);//add it to the stage
}
//enemy1
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//adding an eFrame function
function eFrame(e:Event):void{
    //if there aren't any levels left
if(currentLvl > enemyArray.length){
    gameOver=true;//set the game to be over

    //reset all the stats
    currentLvl = 1;
    currentEnemy = 0;
    enemyTime = 0;
    enemyLimit = 12;
    enemiesLeft = 0;

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//remove this listener
    removeChild(roadHolder);//remove the pieces of road
    gotoAndStop('win');//go to the win frame
}
if(lives<=0){//if the user runs out of lives
    gameOver=true;//set the game to be over

    //reset all the stats
    currentLvl = 1;
    currentEnemy = 0;
    enemyTime = 0;
    enemyLimit = 12;
    enemiesLeft = 0;

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//remove this listener
    removeChild(roadHolder);//remove the pieces of road
    gotoAndStop('lose');//go to the lose frame
}
    makeEnemies();//we'll just make some enemies
    if(enemiesLeft==0){//if there are no more enemies left
    currentLvl ++;//continue to the next level
    currentEnemy = 0;//reset the amount of enemies there are
    start2Game();
    startGame();//restart the game
}
//Updating the text fields
txtLevel.text = 'Level '+currentLvl;
txtMoney.text = '$'+money;
txtLives.text = 'Lives: '+lives;
txtEnemiesLeft.text = 'Enemies Left:  '+enemiesLeft;

}

function makeEnemies():void{//this function will add enemies to the field
    if(enemyTime < enemyLimit){//if it isn't time to make them yet
        enemyTime ++;//then keep on waiting
    } else {//otherwise
        var theCode:int = enemyArray[currentLvl-1][currentEnemy];//get the code from the array
        if(theCode == 2){//if it's set as 1
            var newEnemy:Enemy = new Enemy();//then create a new enemy
            enemyHolder.addChild(newEnemy);//and add it to the enemyholder
        }
        currentEnemy ++;//move on to the next enemy
        enemyTime = 0;//and reset the time
    }
}
//enemy2
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, e2Frame);//adding an eFrame function
function e2Frame(e:Event):void{
    //if there aren't any levels left
if(currentLvl > enemyArray.length){
    gameOver=true;//set the game to be over

    //reset all the stats
    currentLvl = 1;
    currentEnemy2 = 0;
    enemy2Time = 0;
    enemy2Limit = 12;
    enemiesLeft = 0;

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, eFrame);//remove this listener
    removeChild(roadHolder);//remove the pieces of road
    gotoAndStop('win');//go to the win frame
}
if(lives<=0){//if the user runs out of lives
    gameOver=true;//set the game to be over

    //reset all the stats
    currentLvl = 1;
    currentEnemy2 = 0;
    enemy2Time = 0;
    enemy2Limit = 12;
    enemiesLeft = 0;

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, e2Frame);//remove this listener
    removeChild(roadHolder);//remove the pieces of road
    gotoAndStop('lose');//go to the lose frame
}
    makeEnemies2();//we'll just make some enemies

    if(enemiesLeft==0){//if there are no more enemies left
    currentLvl ++;//continue to the next level
    currentEnemy2 = 0;//reset the amount of enemies there are
    start2Game();
    startGame();//restart the game
}
    //Updating the text fields
txtLevel.text = 'Level '+currentLvl;
txtMoney.text = '$'+money;
txtLives.text = 'Lives: '+lives;
txtEnemiesLeft.text = 'Enemies Left:  '+enemiesLeft;

}

function makeEnemies2():void{//this function will add enemies to the field
    if(enemy2Time < enemy2Limit){//if it isn't time to make them yet
        enemy2Time ++;//then keep on waiting
    } else {//otherwise
        var theCode:int = enemyArray[currentLvl-1][currentEnemy2];//get the code from the array
        if(theCode == 2){//if it's set as 1
            var newEnemy2:Enemy2 = new Enemy2();//then create a new enemy
            enemyHolder.addChild(newEnemy2);//and add it to the enemyholder
        }
        currentEnemy2 ++;//move on to the next enemy
        enemy2Time = 0;//and reset the time
    }
}
//other
//run these functions at the start
makeRoad();
var enemyHolder:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(enemyHolder);
startGame();
start2Game();
```

Comment: One of the hardest things to get right in game development is ensuring that **nothing** is left over / overflowing from the previous level. Best thing to do is have a level class that holds arrays for all your enemies and stuff and contains a `dispose()` function or similar. Whenever you write code that will add data to the level, make sure you update the `dispose()` function to remove this information.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty painful. Might do yourself some justice looking at game engines that handle this stuff for you, like PushButton. Haven't looked into it much myself tbh cause I use my own engine, but apparently it's really good: http://pushbuttonengine.com/

Comment: im still a little confused about this maybe you can help me more with the code

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the ability to reset your game state easily. Remove listeners (might not be needed if you use weak references; http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_weakly_refe.html), clear arrays, remove graphics (removeChild) etc. Storing everything in a "level" object and having a dispose() (or similar) function on that is a nice way of doing it (as mentioned in comments). Then simply create a new level object for the next level, and you are good to go :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the problem you're having is that you aren't removing everything from the level properly before you start the next level.

Here's how the "loading of the game" should work:

1. Set up all in-game static assets. (HUD, Tiles, etc)
2. Set up all the Tower Elements (Buying panel for towers)
3. Set up all the Enemy Elements. (Create the array that represents
   the enemies that will spawn)
4. Continue setting up all other elements you have in-game.

After they've finished playing this level, whether it be win/lose, you should remove ALL things that were added during the "loading" phase.

The idea here is that you want everything to be loaded, each new level, the exact same way every time you do it with small changes to the level like design.  Things like enemies and tower assets will always be loaded the same way, so you need to make sure you remove them properly before the next rounds starts so that when you do add them for that round, you aren't re-adding something that still exists in-game.

You seem confused about game design in general.  The problem I mentioned above is just one of the many trip-ups when beginning the designing of games.  I'd recommend that you go through a game-design book.  I'd recommend [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789747324).  The reason I recommend a book like this is because it walks you through the conceptual portion of game design and gets you thinking correctly.  I learned Game Programming from this book and recently coded [Symphonic Tower Defense](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/576557).